# renting a movie entity

Tags: database, database-design

Here I have a `Movie` entity with all the attributes I need. What I am having trouble understanding is what if the DVD store has more than one copy and more than one format of each movie. For example, each copy of these movies is identified with the combination of  Movie_ID and item copy number. So what I mean is when a customer rents a Movie Item, he/she actually rents a copy of the Movie - called an item. Example:  "Batman" is a Movie...but your DVD copy at home is an Item.  So what gets me lost is a customer can rent copies of the same of different Movie Items according to his/her quota. Is this ok what I did ? If not, what is one of the ways to do it ?

Comment: What does your current ER Diagram look like?

Comment: this is what I have so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hop the draft model helps you:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Movie item represents the copy of the movie right? the actual disk itself?

Lets rename it for now so i can explain better of course you can rename it to your liking.

Lets call it ProductInformation for now. 
so you have a productinformation which in this case is linked to a movie. the ProductInformation needs to have an extra value however it needs to know if its a DVD Blue-Ray or something else.

So we will create another entity called ProductType. this should contain an ID and a TypeName which will contain the values DVD, Blue-Ray or something else.

Create a One to Many relationship between ProductType and ProductInformation.

There, now we have a productInformation with a type and a movie linked to it!
Add CurrentPrice and IsRental columns to this entity remove the price and isrental property from the movie entity.

You should change the relationship between productInformation and Movie as so:
One movie can have many ProductInformation, one ProductInformation can have only one Movie.

Now lets make a Product Entity. The product Entity will represent the actual product (the physical DVD, Blue-Ray or something else).
It will have an ID, maybe a barcode if applicable since it is a store.

Lets create a relationship between the ProductInformation and Product, one product can have one productInformation, one productInformation can have many products.

Now Remove the relationships you've had between your user (rename user to customer) and movie. movie is not physical, the customer will not rent a movie, it will rent a product. movie is nothing more but information about the product.

Now we need to create an entity ProductCustomer or maybe name it Transaction.
This will take care of our many to many relationship between users and products.

Give it an Id, ProductId, CustomerId, Price (Hey we added that at our ProductInformation didnt we?!, Yes we did, but prices change. the transaction will be in the database forever. so for bookkeeping purposes we need to give it a Price aswell, so that we know how much a customer had paid at that time.) move the properties rentaldate and returndate from movie to this entity (productcustomer or transaction), and remove them at movie. aaaand you should have everything fixed, all your worries should be resolved.

Sorry i cant draw a diagram for you, only just got this laptop. :-)
Hope my explanation says as much as a diagram would.