# what are the differences between inventory and products in a POS system?

Tags: database, database-design, inventory, inventory-management

I'm trying to make the database system point of sale, however I am confused between the entity and product inventory entity. What are the differences between product and inventory?

I know that the inventory should control the amount of product available .... but i have all that in products.

```
product code 
name 
description 
cost 
unit price 
Subcategory code 
brand code 
amount available 
Minimum quantity for rehearing 
state 
tax code 
weight 
amount wholesales 
wholesales price 
perishable 
due date 
creation date 
upgrade date
```

what i should have in inventory? I have researched and according to what I read I need to have the product, the description, the quantity, purchase price, sale price, profit or gain and date of the transactions. But almost everything is in the Products table, what should I do?

Comment: For one thing, storing it as a field and not calculating it based on the number of transactions that happen is sort of dangerous - it's way too volatile and there isn't enough data to help keep an audit trail.

Comment: Which are you referring  specifically?

Comment: Meaning don't store "amount available" as a field - calculate it since that will leave a trail if there is loss.

Comment: If you mean the amount, the calculation is not based on transactions because it is a very small-scale program, however I have a record of all transactions created.

Comment: Now i understand i have to move all transaction data to inventory and how you recommend me patricksweeney i will calculate in the number of transactions.

Comment: This may [come in handy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343180/renting-a-movie-entity/21412456#21412456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can store the inventory in the products table. There will certainly be transaction tables for purchases for the products and sales and even adjusting records (when items get count and the number differs from what's stored in the database), but you can easily work with the stock stored in the production table itself, thus not having to scan the whole database and sum up all purchases and sales and corrections every time (and never being able to delete old transaction data from the database, as that would invalidate the calculations).

However there are reasons to have stock stored in an inventory table instead. For instance if you want to store different statusses, e.g. you have 100 pieces in store plus twenty just arrived and still unchecked. Or you have a store with goods plus a warehouse housing additional stock. Or you have charges (different model numbers for example for a slightly altered product) which you offer as the same product, but still want to know how many old and how many new ones are in stock. And so on.

So make your mind up, if you want to store additional data with product stock, which would result in an 1:n relation instead of 1:1 which you have now.

Answer (score 2):

A Product is an abstract Good or Service. A Good is the specification of an Asset.

Example "2014 Mazda 3" is a good. A "2014 Mazda 3 with VIN 12345" is an Asset.

A Catalog is the list of products that you want to sell. They don't need to exist yet, or you could be selling them for someone else.

Items Held For Sale are assets that you keep around to sell. These could be consigned (owned by someone else).

Inventory is an accounting concept. It is the dollar value of the items held for sale that you own, plus inbound and outbound goods that you're responsible for, plus any costs associated with holding that inventory.

You can track the value of inventory in a variety of ways such as FIFO and LIFO